# UISearchbar searchBarTextDidEndEditing not being called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

So I have this code -

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"SEARCH BAR TEXT DID END EDITING");
    [self handleSearchForSearchString:searchBar.text];
}

-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"SEARCH BAR BEGIN EDITING");
    if(shouldBeginEditing) {
        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: animationDuration];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton: YES animated:YES];
    }
    BOOL boolToReturn = shouldBeginEditing;
    shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    return boolToReturn;
}
```

`searchBarShouldBeginEditing` is being called, but `searchBarTextDidEndEditing` is not being called. Why is that happening?

Comment: Did you set the delegates to the UISearchBar?

Comment: @Tendulkar: This time bowled at 0. **searchBarShouldBeginEditing is being called, but searchBarTextDidEndEditing is not being called.**

Comment: ^except that doesn't have an answer... - why should I implement the clicked method when I clearly want things to happen after the user has stopped editing?

Answer (score 1):

Implement Below method

**searchBarSearchButtonClicked**

and make sure you [UISearchchbar resignfirstresponder] in the method mentioned above.